# Decomposition semi-simple linear algebraic groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Is there a isomorphism between a semi-simple linear algebraic group and product of simple linear algebraic groups？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following result, see the lecture notes of [Milne](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.1348.pdf), page $5$, for characteristic zero:

COROLLARY $4.4$. An algebraic group is semisimple if and only if it is an almost direct product of almost-simple algebraic groups.

Comment: Right. You may want to add an example, say, the semisimple group $SO(4)$: It is not a product of simple Lie groups, but its universal covering group $Spin(4)$ is.